# The relation between concavity/convexity and slant asymptotes

Tags: calculus

There's a question I have been asked the other day that really bothers me but I can't seem to prove it.

Let's say $f\left(x_2\right)>f\left(x_1\right)\:for\:every\:x_2>x_1>0$ and $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}\right)=m\:,\:\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(f\left(x\right)-mx\right)=n$ exist and finite.

Also, $(c, f(c))$ is concave to convex point and for every $x>c$ there are no extrema or inflection points.

That brings me to the question, under these circumstances, is $f(c) > m*c+n$?